# how to convert number into date in unconventional format

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a text file that record dates in american format(MMDDYY, e.g 070715). I am wondering if there is an easy way to convert that into date, as I need to do date calculation. I notice there is a date command to allow you to convert string into date ( date -d "string") but it can only read the date in certain ways. I may be able to do some substring manipulation to convert to the desired format, but it seems like there should be a lot more simple way to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using BASH string manipulation you can do:

```
s='070515'
date -d "20${s: -2}-${s:0:2}-${s:2:2}"
Sun Jul  5 00:00:00 EDT 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert MMDDYY to, say, YYYYMMDD with `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)/20\3\1\2/'
```

This assumes that (a) all dates in 21st century (20xx) and (b) the dates are the only or at least the first field in your file.  If not, more complicated expressions could be used.